# How to hide application from search list in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, search

I would like to hide the application from search list, i.e. when a user tries to search any application in Windows 8 through the search option, the application will not appear in search result.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean a desktop application or a Metro application?

Comment: applications searched by search option for metro or desktop any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application you wish to hide is a desktop application:

1. search for it on Start Screen like you usually would
2. right-click on the icon
3. choose *Open file location* from the bottom menu
4. now you have two options:

   - remove the shortcut (it will also disappear from the Start Menu)
   - rename the shortcut (it will be kept in the Start Menu and still be searchable, but with a different name)

Repeat this process until all shortcuts to the application you wish to hide disappear.

As for metro applications, I'm not sure if it's possible to remove them from the search results. How would you then like to launch them?